# Want to vary speed on 12 volt DC RV ceiling fan

Tags: motor-controller, 12v, variable

I have a 700 cm 12 volt DC RV ceiling fan that can work using my 12 volt DC solar power system. I want to figure out a way to vary the speed of the fan.

Comment: Is the fan motor brushclesss (BLDC) or brushed. If brushed simple PWM should work. If BLDC you need to "talk to" the controller.

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to reduce the speed is to use a PWM circuit. The simple way is to put some resistance in series with the fan. The maximum value of resistance should be not much more than 12 volts divided by the current that the fan takes while running.